# Django - Paginator.get_page() in ListViews

Tags: django-views

I am using django 3.2

ListView uses "Paginator.page(number)" for pagination. I would like to use "Paginator.get_page(number)".

If this is my views what should I do to use "Paginator.get_page(number)"?

```
class MyList(ListView):
      model = MyModel
      template_name = "template.html"
      paginate_by = 5
```

and as an extra I would like to use "Paginator.get_elided_page_range(number, *, on_each_side=3, on_ends=2)"

Thanks.